# Im trying to do stack with linked list in c++ with two structs, I have a run time error when trying to add number to the stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

i have 4 files, stack.cpp, stack.h, linkedlist.cpp and linkedlist.h, im trying to do stuck that based on linked list the struct of the stack is a pointer to the linked list struct. I have run time error when i trying add number to the stuck (push), it says that the head_ref is null (Exception thrown - head_ref was nullptr)

linkedlist.h

```
#pragma once
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void addToTop(node** head_ref, int new_data);
int removeFirstNode(node* head);
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "LinkedList.h"

/* a positive-integer value stack, with no size limit */
typedef struct Stack
{
    struct node* front;
} Stack;

void push(Stack* s, unsigned int element);
int pop(Stack* s); // Return -1 if stack is empty

void initStack(Stack* s);
void cleanStack(Stack* s);

bool isEmpty(Stack* s);
bool isFull(Stack* s);

#endif // STACK_H
```

linkedlist.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
void addToTop(node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    node* ptr = new node;
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        ptr->data = new_data;
        *head_ref = ptr;
    }
    else
    {  
        ptr->data = new_data;
        ptr->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = ptr;
    }
}

int removeFirstNode(struct node* head)
{
    int num = 0;
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Move the head pointer to the next node
    node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    num = head->data;
    delete temp;

    return num;
}
```

stack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

void initStack(Stack* s)
{

    s = new Stack;
    s->front = new node;
    s->front->data = 0;
    s->front->next = NULL;
}
void cleanStack(Stack* s)
{
    delete s->front;
}
void push(Stack* s, unsigned int element)
{
    addToTop(&s->front, element);
}
    
int pop(Stack* s)
{
    int pop = 0;
    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        std::cout << "The stack is empty!";
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        pop = removeFirstNode(s->front->next);
        return pop;
    }
}

bool isEmpty(Stack* s)
{
    return(s == NULL);
}

bool isFull(Stack* s)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add the error you're getting in your question.

Comment: Your `initStack` function is incorrect. If you are using that function that probably explains the problem.

Comment: Maybe try using a reference `void initStack(Stack*& s)`. The extra `&` makes all the difference.

Comment: If you debugged your code, you should have seen that the pointer you passed to `initStack` was not changed by that function.  Also, you should post a [mcve].

Comment: But the correct way to code this would be to turn `initStack` into a constructor and `cleanStack` into a destructor.